# ROS2 colcon build not showing any error messages in windows

Tags: c++, windows, build, ros2

While building the ROS2 publisher on the windows by using `colcon` build, there are no error messages shown for debug, only shown failed or finished.

I have try using "`colcon --log-level info build`" or "`colcon --log-level debug build`", but still in vain.

Is there any way to let the `colcon` build shown the error messages if there are some bugs in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use **colcon build --event-handlers console_cohesion+**

[ros answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/322780/ros2-colcon-build-on-windows-no-error-message-shown-when-it-failed/)

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why this is not the default. It is very confusing to see the builds fail without any feedback.